# Broken packages in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, apt, package-management, dependencies

When I run the `apt-get upgrade` command I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libvlc5 : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180305+r74659+127~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not installed
vlc : Depends: vlc-bin (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180210+r74136+127~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not installed
   Depends: vlc-plugin-base (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180210+r74136+127~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not installed
   Depends: vlc-plugin-qt (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180210+r74136+127~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not installed
   Depends: vlc-plugin-video-output (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180210+r74136+127~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I already tried apt-get install -f. This is the output:

```
(Reading database ... 568381 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libvlccore9_4.0.0~rc1~~git20180305+r74659+127~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvlccore9:amd64 (4.0.0~rc1~~git20180305+r74659+127~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlccore9_4.0.0~rc1~~git20180305+r74659+127~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.9.0.0', which is also in package libvlccore8:amd64 3.0.0~~git20171210+r73147+99~ubuntu16.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlccore9_4.0.0~rc1~~git20180305+r74659+127~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you add new recent repos? If it's true, maybe recent repos isn't compatible with your distro. Did you try 'apt-get update && apt-get upgrade' before trying to install new package?

Comment: Sorry for my comment, I omit 'apt-get upgrade' phrase. Please try 'apt-get clean' and 'apt-get update' again. Maybe old cache is preventing correct update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You’re using the [VLC daily master branch build PPA](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily), which explicitly states

> CAUTION:
>   The builds in this archive are fully automated, and do not go through any quality assurance whatsoever. Build breaks and functional regressions occur frequently.
>
> DO NOT USE this archive if you are not prepared to cope with such problems.

It appears you shouldn’t be using this archive.

You should remove it from your repositories, run `apt update`, uninstall `vlc` and all related packages, then re-install them (which will install the version available from whatever other repositories you have configured).